# Rails migration: primary key id with unsigned int(10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I want to define primary key id as below in my tables through rails migration

`id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`

I am using mysql db.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do this?

Comment: for better performance which I have not decided myself only :)

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer to avoid custom SQL in migrations this will work as well:

```
create_table(:user, id: false,  primary_key: :id) do |t|
  t.primary_key :id, :unsigned_integer, null: false, default: :null, auto_increment: true
  t.string :name
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `#execute` with the SQL you need inside your migration.

```
execute "ALTER TABLE things MODIFY id UNSIGNED(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT"
```

Or if the column doesn't yet exist at all:

```
execute "ALTER TABLE things ADD COLUMN id UNSIGNED(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY"
```

That should work fine.  I think in your migrations it's fine to drop down to pure SQL, and in many cases it's necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I worked out with this

```
create_table things, :id => false do |t|
  t.column :id, 'INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (id)'
  t.string :name
  ...
```

OR

```
create_table things, :id => false do |t|
  t.column :id, ID_COLUMN
  t.string :name
  ...
```

where ID_COLUMN defined in some config/module and used in other migrations as well

Answer (score 1):

Rails 5.2 does accept unsigned

```
t.integer     :amount,          null: false, unsigned: true
```